# Create indirect relationships and return the sum of two relationships

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have a program to share services between people. Basically I am facing a problem trying to get the conversations between users. Here is the idea:
My program allows users to offer services to other users, but also to acquire services from other users. Each user can register an unlimited number of services.
When a user finds a service that he/she wants to get, he creates a deal and starts a conversation with the counterpart.
The structure of my tables is the following (I am only including the relationship columns):

**Users table**

```
id // This is the user identifier
```

**Services table**

```
id // This is the service identifier
user_id // This is the identifier of the user who created the service
```

**Deals table**

```
id // This is the deal identifier
user_id // This is the identifier of the user acquiring the service
service_id // This is the identifier of the service being acquired in this deal
```

**Conversations table**

```
id // This is the identifier of the conversation
deal_id // This is the identifier of the deal that the conversation belongs to
```

Here is my problem:
I want to be able to retrieve the conversations for each user, both as applicant and as a seller.

I created this relationship (in **`User.php`**) for conversations in which the user is acquiring the service:

```
    public function conversationsApplicant(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough( Conversations::class, Deal::class );
    }
```

I would like to create also the conversationsSeller() function

```
    public function conversationsSeller(){
        return $this->????;
    }
```

I am guessing I should add some kind of relationship between a Conversation and a Service in **`Service.php`**. It would be something like `$this->services()->with( 'deals' )->with( 'conversations' );`

The final goal would be to have a method that returns both relationships in one `$user->conversations()->get()`.

```
public function conversations(){
    return $this->conversationsApplicant() + $this->conversationsSeller();
}
```

To retrieve the relationship I was thinking that maybe there is a workaround using a SQL query, but I am not sure if that will return the relationship as I need it. Here is the query that I need to perform:

```
SELECT
    conversations.*
FROM
    mydb.conversations, mydb.services, mydb.users, mydb.deals
WHERE
    users.id = services.user_id AND
    services.id = deals.service_id AND
    deals.id = conversations.deal_id AND
    users.id = $user->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you implement **merged relationship** simply

```
public function getCombinedChats($value)
{
    // There two calls return collections
    // as defined in relations.
    $Applicant= $this->conversationsApplicant;
    $Seller= $this->conversationsSeller;

    // Merge collections and return single collection.
    return $Applicant->merge($Seller);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that solves half of the question. Now I just need to be able to retrieve the conversationsSeller relationship.